# react native (expo app) azure ad b2c configuration

Tags: react-native, azure, azure-active-directory, expo

I am trying to put together a POC for learning purposes. I would like to use Azure AD B2C to authenticate my app client.

The app client is an expo react native app. I have found a library `ad-b2c-react-native` that is supposed to help me handle the authentication.

I don't know how to set up my azure AD B2C application in order to work with this library. Here is the code I have right now.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AuthProvider
        tenant="tenantName"
        appId="24c9fd0c-f595-485d-REST"
        loginPolicy="B2C_1_weatherappflow>"
        passwordResetPolicy="B2C_1_weatherappflow"
        profileEditPolicy="B2C_1_weatherappflow"
        redirectURI="https://APPNAME.b2clogin.com/oauth2/nativeclient"
      >
        <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Authenticated></Authenticated>
      </AuthProvider>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The Authenticated component

```
const Authenticated = () => {
  const { getTokensAsync, isLoading, error, isAuthentic } = useToken();

  useEffect(() => {
    const login = async () => {
      console.log("I was called to log in.");

      const token = await getTokensAsync();

      console.log("I am logged in: ", token);
    };

    login();
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
```

In Azure I have a Mobile/Desktop application redirect URI as the following:

```
https://APPNAME.b2clogin.com/oauth2/nativeclient
```

UPDATE: When I run the app using expo's browser view: it opens a new browser window that just shows: `Bad Request`, while on the phone it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong, how the redirects should be set up?

I checked the URI that produces the Bad Request text and it ends with `scope=24c9fd0c-f595-485d-8aa1-REST%20offline_access`

So essentially, it is requesting the `offline_access` scope which doesn't exist? I am not sure..

UPDATE #2: I have identified that the tenant in the config should be the tenant's name instead of it's ID, but still get the same Bad Request returned..

Comment: I updated the code, now it opens a new browser window running with expo web, that shows Bad Request. On phone using the expo app, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Check this Document if it help [Configure authentication in a sample React SPA by using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-react-spa-app.md)